# VBA If textbox is empty display all values

Tags: vba, ms-access, string, ms-query

I have 2 textboxes and a button. The button opens a query with the values of the textboxes. Everything works fine, except when one textbox is empty then I want to find all the records from that textbox(So far I've tested it on textbox2). Here is my code:

```
Private Sub vbaBtn_Click()

Dim af1 As String, af2 As String
 af1 = "([a1]='" + [krit1] + "') "

If krit2 = "" Then
 af2 = "([a2]='" + "*" + "') "
Else
 af2 = "([a2]='" + [krit2] + "') "
End If

DoCmd.OpenForm "FormLisategevusalad", acFormDS, , af1 & " " & "And" & " " & af2

End Sub
```

It seems to me, that VBA is always choosing the Else option not the If one, since when I debugged it said the error is an "Invalid use of null" and pointed to the Else condition.

Am I using a wrong method to detect and empty string? If I get the empty string recognition to work, is this `af2 = "([a2]='" + "*" + "') "` the right way to return all records?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In table design, have you set to'No' the field 'Allow Zero Length'. krit2 might be Null, not "". You can google Zero Length Strings or look at this: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070128045303AAZu8fM. I don't guarantee this is the answer, just something to be clear on.

Comment: @user2204315
Hello, thank You for the reply it gave me an idea. Although at the moment it wont help me sadly, cause i have zero-length values in table2. I will try different workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty textbox holds the value of Null, thus concatenating this with + results in a Null. Use &:

```
Private Sub vbaBtn_Click()

    Dim af1 As String, af2 As String

    af1 = "([a1]='" & [krit1] & "') "

    If IsNull([krit2]) Then
        af2 = "([a2] Is Not Null) "
    Else
        af2 = "([a2]='" & [krit2] & "') "
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenForm "FormLisategevusalad", acFormDS, ,af1 & " And " & af2

End Sub
```